# Why css border-radius is causing element to disappear in this bare minimum Angular Material Sidenav conponent? (demo provided)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

This is regarding [Angular Material Sidenav component](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview). In the below code, when I increase the border-radius so that when it overlaps the enclosing element, the element disappears.

```html
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
    Drawer content <br />
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content
    style="
      border-radius: 0px; // <-- try to increase this value to see effect
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: stretch;
      align-items: stretch;
      background-color: rgb(255, 200, 200);
    "
    >Main content</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

*(content visible when no border radius)*
[image]

*(content vanishes when border radius is added)*
[image]

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/7swnhp?file=src%2Fexample%2Fsidenav-drawer-overview-example.html

I couldn't see where the element goes, couldn't see any hiding styles being applied, in the DOM I can see it is there, but it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

When I added border-raduis, it works as expected, content is visible.

[image: works as expected]

Comment: Could this be a browser issue? I'm on Ubuntu 22, Chrome Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (64-bit). (I'm not the one downvoted, sorry)

Comment: It should not be a browser issue. can you share a fiddle where you apply the border-radius and content is not visible. Just to be double sure. (Downvote is because this is not an answer. Ideally it should have been a comment.)